# Error when posting to Facebook wall with API: Error occured (#100) link URL is not properly formatted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the code:

```
attachment = { message:'', name: 'post title', caption: 'user just did something',
                    link: 'post URL', action_links: [{ text: 'action link test', href: 'http://example.com'}]
                  };



FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', attachment, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured ' + response.error.message);
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Any clues?

Comment: The post is successful, but the action link -- which was the crux of the original problem -- still doesn't appear. What are we doing wrong with the action links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put a string 'post URL' for the `link`. `link` has to be a properly formatted URL like `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: ok, we're pretty stupid. we were so focused on the action link stuff, we forgot we had replaced the link code as well. thanks! egg on our face.

Comment: The post is successful, but the action link -- which was the crux of the original problem -- still doesn't appear. What are we doing wrong with the action links?

Comment: could you post that as a new question? I have no experience using action_link, and if you post as new then it will be more likely to be seen by more coders.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem ... the issue was in the message (description) . i had an invalid URL. in my case i used a link to a non existing facebook page. it seems that facebook checks the validity of the page before linking it from the description. just check all your links before adding them in a posting description

i just fixed the url and every thing worked fine